# In The Same Column, Get The Date Difference As Days

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I've written a simple query that returns the last two attendance records of a person and here is a sample how it works:

```
Id      Date
305351  1/24/2018
305351  1/23/2018
E5671   10/12/2014
E5671   10/11/2014
```

**The Query**:

```
----Retrieve days from date difference - Starts
SELECT T1.EMPNO,
         T1.ATT_DATE
FROM (
     SELECT T2.EMPNO, T2.ATT_DATE,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T2.EMPNO ORDER BY T2.ATT_DATE DESC) as rn
            FROM TableName T2 
     )  T1
WHERE T1.rn <= 2
----Retrieve days from date difference - Ends
```

The above works well and now I am trying to get days from the date difference. Tried the following but returns incorrect days between two dates from the rows with a `JOIN` to the employee id:

```
TO_DATE(T1.ATT_DATE) - TO_DATE(T3.ATT_DATE) "DAYS"
```

**Expected Output**:

```
 Id      Date      Days
305351  1/24/2018  1
305351  1/23/2018  1
E5671   10/12/2014 1
E5671   10/11/2014 1
```

I am guessing, made a silly mistake here and would expect an idea to make it work - Thanks.

**Update 1** - The output could be the following:

**Expected Output**:

```
Id      Date      Days
305351  1/24/2018  1 //(24-01-2018) - (23-01-2018) = Day 1 
E5671   10/12/2014 1 //(12-01-2018) - (11-01-2018) = Day 1
```

Comment: Why do ***all*** the rows have a difference of 1 day?  Surely the sequence of `23rd, 24th, 25th` has differences of `nothing-to-compare-to, 1 day, 1 day`?  *(Represented as `NULL, 1, 1`.)*

Comment: You can see the updated output @MatBailie.

Comment: So which of those two possible expected outputs do you want? Either is possible. And either way, what do you want to see if there is only a single record for an ID in the source table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag()` and `lead()`.  For instance:

```
SELECT T1.EMPNO, T1.ATT_DATE,
       (T1.ATT_DATE - T1.prev_att_date) as Days
FROM (SELECT T2.*,
             LAG(T2.ATT_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY t2.EMPNO ORDER BY t2.ATT_DATE) as prev_att_date
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T2.EMPNO ORDER BY T2.ATT_DATE DESC) as rn
      FROM TableName T2 
     )  T1
WHERE T1.rn <= 2;
```

This puts the days to the *previous* record on each row, so the values are not necessarily the same.  Your question is unclear on whether the values should be the same on each row or whether the number should be to the previous value.

Comment: This looks promising @Gordon Linoff and will be trying it. Basically my concept is I should retrieve the last date `1/24/2018` and the **Days** column should be a value comparing/subtracting the last two rows (1st - `1/24/2018` and 2nd `1/23/2018` latest date).

Comment: You are just too good @Gordon Linoff and learnt a new thing - Thanks.